# Adding elements to a collection of lists

Tags: list-manipulation

I would like to add element `a` at the start of a series of lists.

For example I have a collection of lists called

```
LISTS1 = {{1,2,3,4,5},{2,3,4,5,6},{3,4,5,6,7},{4,5,6,7,8}}
```

Now I want to add a `0` to the beginning of the first list, two `0`s to the second list and so on, to get:

```
{{0,1,2,3,4,5},{0,0,2,3,4,5,6},{0,0,0,3,4,5,6,7},{0,0,0,0,4,5,6,7,8}}.
```

I suspect this needs to be done using the `Prepend` command in combination with something to change the numbers of elements to add for each individual list in the collection.

Answer (score 10):

This would be a neat way to do it:

```
LISTS1 = {{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, {2, 3, 4, 5, 6}, {3, 4, 5, 6, 7}, {4, 5, 6, 7, 8}};

MapIndexed[Join[Table[0, #2], #1] &, LISTS1]
```

> {{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, {0, 0, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}, {0, 0, 0, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8}}

Answer (score 7):

One possibility without particular attention to performance:

Sample input:

```
data = {{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, {2, 3, 4, 5, 6}, {3, 4, 5, 6, 7}, {4, 5, 6, 7, 8}}
```

Let's generate the zeros ...

```
zeros = ConstantArray[0, #] & /@ Range@Length[data]
```

... and prepend them to the sublists:

```
MapThread[Join, {zeros, data}]
```

Answer (score 7):

This is how I would do it:

`Table[Join[Table[0, {j, i}], LISTS1[[i]]], {i, Length[LISTS1]}]`

Answer (score 7):

A variation of Szabolcs's method with extra speed and *infix!* ;-)

```
list = {{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, {2, 3, 4, 5, 6}, {3, 4, 5, 6, 7}, {4, 5, 6, 7, 8}};

Join[
 0 ~ConstantArray~ # & ~Array~ Length@list,
 list,
 2
]
```

Comment: Naughty naughty... a gem for the infixionado.Strong stuff ;-)

Comment: Horrible, horrible to read. However, it has the advantage that `ConstantArray` returns a packed array, and using the third argument of `Join` is always nice.

Answer (score 6):

A slight variation of Chris's answer:

```
LISTS1 = {{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, {2, 3, 4, 5, 6}, {3, 4, 5, 6, 7}, {4, 5, 6, 7, 8}};

MapIndexed[ArrayPad[#1, {First[#2], 0}] &, LISTS1]
```

Answer (score 5):

Two variations of `MapThread` and `MapIndexed`:

`MapThread` with `PadLeft`:

```
  MapThread[PadLeft[#1, #2 + Length@#1] &, {LISTS1,Range@Length[LISTS1]}]
```

`MapIndexed` with `PadLeft`:

```
   MapIndexed[PadLeft[#, #2 + Length@#1] &, LISTS1]
```

Answer (score 4):

A slight variant:

```
Join[ ConstantArray[0, #], LISTS1[[#]]] & /@ Range@Length@LISTS1
```

giving

```
(* {{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, {0, 0, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}, {0, 0, 0, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7}, 
    {0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8}} *)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
ls = {{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, {2, 3, 4, 5, 6}, {3, 4, 5, 6, 7}, {4, 5, 6, 7, 8}};
Join[0 Range@Range@Length@ls, ls, 2]

(*{{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, {0, 0, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}, {0, 0, 0, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7},
  {0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8}}*)
```