# Prepend 0 to sublists

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix

My question is similar to [this one](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/4812/73), but my goal is to prepend a *single* 0 the each sublist, not incrementally many 0's.

The file I'm working is a CSV containing around 50K sublists of length 35.

I've tried to `Riffle` my `Flatten[list,1]` and then `Partition` it into properly sized sublists, but the result isn't pretty - I might have to add an offset parameter.

Also, I'm trying to learn how to use pure functions, so any suggestion using them will be of help!

Comment: `PadLeft[#,6]&/@lists`

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
lists = RandomInteger[{1, 9}, {4, 5}]
```

> ```
> {{7, 4, 9, 9, 7},
>  {4, 2, 5, 5, 2},
>  {6, 5, 9, 2, 4},
>  {1, 9, 4, 7, 2}}
> ```

```
ArrayPad[lists, {0, {1, 0}}]
```

> ```
> {{0, 7, 4, 9, 9, 7},
>  {0, 4, 2, 5, 5, 2},
>  {0, 6, 5, 9, 2, 4},
>  {0, 1, 9, 4, 7, 2}}
> ```

There are of course many ways to do this.

Since you are interested in learning here are some others, more or less practical:

```
Prepend[#, 0]& /@ lists

Prepend[0] /@ lists   (* version 10 operator form *)

Join[{0} & /@ lists, lists, 2]

{0, ##} & @@@ lists

lists /. {x__Integer} :> {0, x}

PadLeft[#, Dimensions@# + {0, 1}] &@lists
```

---

Rojo expressed doubt about the speed of [`ArrayPad`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ArrayPad.html).  Here are some comparative timings using Packed Arrays, which one should use if speed is a concern:

```
lists = RandomInteger[99, {50000, 35}];

timeAvg = 
  Function[x, 
   Do[If[# > 1, Return[#/5^i]] & @@ Timing@Do[x, {5^i}], {i, 0, 15}], 
   HoldFirst];

Transpose@{ConstantArray[0, Length@#], Sequence @@ Transpose@#} &@lists // timeAvg

ArrayPad[lists, {0, {1, 0}}] // timeAvg

Join[0 ~ConstantArray~ {Length@#, 1}, #, 2] &@lists // timeAvg

ArrayFlatten@{{0, lists}} // timeAvg
```

> 0.00604
>
> 0.0019968
>
> 0.001224
>
> 0.0010032

[`ArrayFlatten`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ArrayFlatten.html) is the fastest, taking 82% as long as [`Join`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Join.html)/[`ConstantArray`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ConstantArray.html) and 50% as long as `ArrayPad`.

Now an unpackable array (strings):

```
lists = RandomChoice["a" ~CharacterRange~ "z", {50000, 35}];

Transpose@{ConstantArray[0, Length@#], Sequence @@ Transpose@#} &@
  lists // timeAvg

ArrayPad[lists, {0, {1, 0}}] // timeAvg

Join[0 ~ConstantArray~ {Length@#, 1}, #, 2] &@lists // timeAvg

ArrayFlatten@{{0, lists}} // timeAvg
```

> 0.023464
>
> 0.024088
>
> 0.024088
>
> 0.08236

Here `ArrayFlatten` takes 342% and 351% as long as the other methods, which are all about the same.

**Conclusion:**  use `ArrayFlatten` when you're sure the data is a packed array of the same type as the value you are inserting; use `Join` or `ArrayPad` when you are not.

Comment: Nice use of the last (numeric) argument of `Join`. I hadn't used it before, but will have to try and remember that one in future as it's clearly quite advantageous.

Comment: Thanks. I've checked the speeds too, and here's [what I got](http://i.stack.imgur.com/CSqT1.png). PadLeft is fastest, with the rule trailing behind.

Comment: @CHM Of those I think PadLeft was fastest for me too, but notice that the `Join` method you tested is *not* the same as the faster one with `ConstantArray`, and ArrayPad is also missing.  By the way, the one you labeled `obscure` is actually the *easiest* for me to read, but then I'm a freak for `##` and `@@@` so `{0, ##} & @@@ x` is pretty much Nirvana. lol

Comment: @CHM thanks for the Accept!

Comment: Thanks to you. At first, `{0, ##} & @@@ lists` was obscure, but I was looking for a pure function, and was served. Now, it seems natural.

Comment: @CHM You're a quick learner in that case.

Answer (score 12):

One convenient method, originally due to [Janus](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/1308/janus) (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2274679/499167)):

```
list = {{1, 2}, {3, 4}, {5, 6}};   

ArrayFlatten@{{0, list}}
```

giving

> (* {{0, 1, 2}, {0, 3, 4}, {0, 5, 6}} *)

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4270825/499167) for some interesting comparisons by [Timo](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/138/timo)

**Edit**

```
MapThread[Prepend[0],{list}]

(* {{0,1,2},{0,3,4},{0,5,6}} *)
```

Comment: Nice! I forgot about this one.  I need to add it to my timings.

Answer (score 11):

```
list = {{1, 2}, {3, 4}, {5, 6}};    
Flatten /@ Tuples[{{0}, list}]
```

> ```
> {{0, 1, 2}, {0, 3, 4}, {0, 5, 6}}
> ```

```
Join @@@ Tuples[{{{0}}, list}]
```

the latter method (thanks to kguler) is even faster than the former one.

These toys haven't been mentioned yet  :

```
Join[ {0}, #] & /@ list

Flatten /@ ({0, #} & /@ list)

MapThread[ Join, {ConstantArray[{0}, Length @ list], list}]

Thread[Join[{0}, Transpose@list]]
```

Comment: @Rojo Thanks, I wanted to use `Tuples` since sometimes it appears to be the best, look here e.g. http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/4748/interlacing-a-single-number-into-a-long-list/4751#4751

Comment: +1, or `Join @@@ Tuples[{{{0}}, lists}]`:)?

Comment: @kguler Thanks, I'll add this, seems even faster than `Flatten /@ Tuples[{{0}, list}]`.

Answer (score 8):

One (exotic) way is by using `Flatten` with its second argument (thanks to Oleksandr for fixing my `Flatten`). For example:

```
list= {{1, 2}, {3, 4}, {5, 6}};
Flatten[{ConstantArray[{0}, Length@#], #}, {{2}, {3, 1}}] &@list
(* {{0, 1, 2}, {0, 3, 4}, {0, 5, 6}} *)
```

See [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/126/5) by Leonid for a detailed explanation on how `Flatten`'s second argument works.

However, this is "slow". Another possibility that's much faster than the above is

```
Transpose@{ConstantArray[0, Length@#], Sequence @@ Transpose@#} &@list
```

A rule based solution for doing the same would be:

```
list /. {x__?NumericQ} :> {0, x};
```

If your list isn't very large (and your CSV file is very modest), then this is perhaps the clearest in intent.

Comment: I beat you to the replacement rule. :^)  Also, you may need to restrict it a bit...

Comment: This question is your 80th in this tag, which means you get a silver tonight. Congrats!

Comment: @OleksandrR. Thanks! I was trying that and observed that `{{2}, {3}}` and `{{2}, {1}}` gave similar, but differently grouped lists and couldn't figure out how to combine them other than with a `Flatten/@`. I'll add that in

Comment: @Oleksandr your method however is considerably slower on the test used on my answer.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard sometimes I wonder if the only reliable way to tell what method's the fastest is to post a question here and compare the different methods people come up with. I guess you pay something for generality, but I wouldn't have expected this to be two orders of magnitude slower than the double-`Transpose` method I posted in chat. As usual, unpacking is the problem here... but that `Join` avoids it while `Flatten` doesn't is surprising to me.

Comment: @Oleksandr Leonid seems to have a better handle on that, but [I have to rely on testing, memory, and `On["Packing"]`](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/5259/121).  Using `Join` over `Flatten` when possible is one of the heuristics I've picked up.

Comment: @R.M. I just realized you were talking to me;  Thanks! :-D

Comment: @mr.w Ah yes, I didn't explicitly @ mention you because yours was the only comment and it should've pinged you, but then Rojo snuck one in a few seconds before I posted, hence not pinging you.

Comment: R.M I didn't notice the name on the comment and I assumed it was someone congratulating *you*.  After all, you're the #1 badge farmer around here. :-)

Comment: @mr.w so that makes you the resident rep farmer? ;)

Comment: @R.M yes, naturally.  Well [Leonid is](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/545/121), I'm just doing a better job. :o)

Answer (score 2):

Using `Cases`:

```
list = {{7, 4, 9, 9, 7}, {4, 2, 5, 5, 2}, {6, 5, 9, 2, 4}, {1, 9, 4, 7, 2}};

Cases[list, x : {__} :> {0, Sequence @@ x}]

(*{{0, 7, 4, 9, 9, 7}, {0, 4, 2, 5, 5, 2}, {0, 6, 5, 9, 2, 4}, {0, 1, 9,4, 7, 2}}*)
```

Answer (score 2):

It's a bit strange for me that no answer used [**Riffle**](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Riffle.html)

With

```
list = RandomInteger[{1, 9}, {4, 5}];
zero = 0~ConstantArray~{Length@list};
```

we do:

```
ArrayReshape[
 Riffle[zero, 
  list], {(Dimensions@list)[[1]], (Dimensions@list)[[2]] + 1}]
```

and we have

> `{{0, 9, 6, 6, 3, 7}, {0, 1, 9, 5, 3, 1}, {0, 4, 7, 7, 3, 2}, {0, 5, 2, 1, 1, 7}}`

from the input

```
list
```

> `{{9, 6, 6, 3, 7}, {1, 9, 5, 3, 1}, {4, 7, 7, 3, 2}, {5, 2, 1, 1, 7}}`

and also