# Fastest way to add a constant column into a array

Tags: performance-tuning

What is the fastest way to add a constant (1 in this test) into a array?
There is my attempt:

```
m=RandomInteger[100,{100000,30}];
(test1={##,1}&@@@m)//AbsoluteTiming//First
(test2=Join[m,ConstantArray[{1},Length@m],2])//AbsoluteTiming//First
(test3=Thread@Append[Transpose@m,1])//AbsoluteTiming//First
(test4=Join[#,{1}]&/@m)//AbsoluteTiming//First
(test5=Append[#,1]&/@m)//AbsoluteTiming//First
(test6=Join[m,{0}&/@m,2])//AbsoluteTiming//First
(test7=ArrayFlatten@{{m,0}})//AbsoluteTiming//First
(test8=ArrayPad[m,{{0,0},{0,1}}])//AbsoluteTiming//First
```

> ```
> 0.304553
> 0.171397
> 0.170948
> 0.054199
> 0.064244
> 0.013391
> 0.010672
> 0.009288
> ```

It's the first way a good answer?

Comment: Murta, I'm closing this because I think it has already been answered.  The methods there should be easily adaptable.  Please let me know if you find this *not* to be the case.  For your packed array I would use: `ArrayFlatten[{{m, 1}}]`

Comment: @Kuba I'm actually [fond](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/3817/826) of that method, and you will see that I included it [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/7997/121).

Comment: I agree.. It's duplicated.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard My comment was addressed to Murta and posted before I've realised your link :)