# Riffle and Partition

Tags: list-manipulation, performance-tuning

At some point I noticed that I was using `Riffle` and `Partition` together a lot. I would do things like

```
Partition[Riffle[{1,2,3},{4,5,6}],2]
```

or

```
Partition[Riffle[{1,2,3}, 6 , {2, -1, 2}], 2]
```

The question is: are better alternatives, in terms of memory and speed?

Comment: `{{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}}\[Transpose]`? 3x speedup. `Thread[{{1, 2, 3}, 6}]` 6x

Comment: @Kuba yup ;). See also my chat with Silvia. Anyway I was focussing on the LibraryLink solution for the second "idiom" first. Also see the functions `betterish` at the bottom of my answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a solution for both "idioms", using LibraryLink and some kind of custom generics. I'm not sure if I like the abstractions, but here is the answer anyway.

```
<< SymbolicC`
<< Developer`
<< CCompilerDriver`
<< CCodeGenerator`
```

The definitions below are made to help abstract this function, so that it works for integers, real numbers and complex numbers.

```
(*lfn is short for library function name*)
(*LL is short for LibraryLink*)

typeTableHeaders = {"type name", "c type", "LL generic name", 
   "abbreviation in lfn"};
typeTable =
  {
   {Integer, "mint", "Integer", "I"},
   {Real, "mreal", "Real", "R"},
   {Complex, "mcomplex", "Complex", "C"}
   };
cTypes = typeTable[[All, 2]];

abstractFunctionName = "parif";

libraryFunctionNames = 
  abstractFunctionName <> "T" <> # <> "_T" & /@ typeTable[[All, 4]];

getters = StringJoin["MArgument_get", #] & /@ typeTable[[All, 3]];

dataGetters = "MTensor_get" <> # <> "Data" & /@ typeTable[[All, 3]];

tensorTypes = "MType_" <> # & /@ typeTable[[All, 3]];

libraryFunctionNamesSingle = # <> "Single" & /@ libraryFunctionNames;
libraryFunctionNamesMulti = # <> "Multi" & /@ libraryFunctionNames;

relations =
  Hold@
   {
    getter -> getters,
    dataGetter -> dataGetters,
    type -> cTypes ,
    tensorType -> tensorTypes
    };

preRules = Thread /@ First@ MapAt[HoldPattern, relations, {1, All, 1}];
```

The next definitions distinguish between the "single" case where we want to riffle with a constant, and the "multi" case where we want to riffle two lists. I have not taken the effort of making this code more expressive. That is, there is some duplicate code.

```
preRulesSingle =
  Append[
   preRules,
   Thread[libraryFunctionName -> libraryFunctionNamesSingle]
   ];

singleDIERule =
  setupSecondInputAccess :> 
   Sequence[
    CDeclare[type, "inputSingleton"], 
    CAssign["inputSingleton", CCall[getter, CArray["Args", 1]]]
    ];

rulesSingle =
  Thread[
   Join[
    preRulesSingle
    ,
    {
     HoldPattern@inputElement -> "inputSingleton",
     HoldPattern@determineNextInputElement :> Sequence[],
     disownIfNeeded :> Sequence[],
     singleDIERule
     }
    ]
   ];

preRulesMulti =
  Append[
   preRules,
   Thread[libraryFunctionName -> libraryFunctionNamesMulti]
   ];


multiDIERule =
  setupSecondInputAccess :> 
   Sequence[
    CDeclare["MTensor", "input2"],
    CAssign["input2", 
     CCall["MArgument_getMTensor", CArray["Args", 1]]],
    CDeclare[CPointerType[type], "input2DataPtr"],
    CAssign[
     "input2DataPtr",
     CCall[CPointerMember["libData", dataGetter], {"input2"}]
     ]
    ];

rulesMulti =
  Thread[
   Join[
    preRulesMulti
    ,
    {
     HoldPattern@inputElement -> CDereference["input2DataPtr"],
     HoldPattern@determineNextInputElement :> 
      COperator[Increment, "input2DataPtr"],
     disownIfNeeded :> 
      CCall[CPointerMember["libData", "MTensor_disown"], "input2"],
     multiDIERule
     }
    ]
   ];
```

Now we construct some SymbolicC with some tokens inside it

```
parifSCHeld =
 Hold@
  CFunction[
   "int"
   ,
   libraryFunctionName
   ,
   {{"WolframLibraryData", "libData"}, {"mint", 
     "Argc"}, {CPointerType["MArgument"], "Args"}, {"MArgument", 
     "Res"}}
   ,

   CBlock[
    {
     CDeclare["int", CAssign["err", "LIBRARY_NO_ERROR"]],
     CDeclare["MTensor", "input"],
     CDeclare["MTensor", "result"],
     CDeclare["int", "inputLength"],
     CDeclare["mint", CArray["resultDimensions", 2]],
     CAssign[
      "input", 
      CCall["MArgument_getMTensor", CArray["Args", 0]]
      ],
     CAssign[
      "inputLength",
      CDereference[
       CCall[
        CPointerMember["libData", "MTensor_getDimensions"],
        {"input"}
        ]
       ]
      ],
     CAssign[
      CArray["resultDimensions", 0],
      "inputLength"
      ],
     CAssign[
      CArray["resultDimensions", 1],
      2
      ]
     ,
     CAssign["err", 
      CCall[
       CPointerMember["libData", "MTensor_new"],
       {tensorType, 2, "resultDimensions", CAddress["result"]}
       ]
      ]
     ,
     CDeclare[CPointerType[type], "inputDataPtr"],
     CAssign[
      "inputDataPtr",
      CCall[
       CPointerMember["libData", dataGetter],
       {"input"}
       ]
      ],
     CDeclare[CPointerType[type], "resultDataPtr"],
     CAssign[
      "resultDataPtr",
      CCall[
       CPointerMember["libData", dataGetter],
       {"result"}
       ]
      ]
     ,
     CDeclare["long", CAssign["iter", 0]]
     ,
     setupSecondInputAccess
     ,
     CWhile[
      COperator[Less, {"iter", "inputLength"}],
      CBlock[
       {
        CAssign[
         CDereference["resultDataPtr"],
         CDereference["inputDataPtr"]
         ],

        COperator[Increment, "resultDataPtr"],
        COperator[Increment, "inputDataPtr"],
        CAssign[
         CDereference["resultDataPtr"],
         inputElement
         ],
        determineNextInputElement,
        COperator[Increment, "resultDataPtr"],
        COperator[Increment, "iter"]
        }
       ]
      ]
     ,
     CCall["MArgument_setMTensor", {"Res", "result"}],
     CCall[CPointerMember["libData", "MTensor_disown"], "input"],
     disownIfNeeded,
     CReturn["err"]
     }
    ]
   ];
```

Now, we turn it into a string, that would normally correspond to the contents of a .c file.

```
symbCWithReplacementsSingle = parifSCHeld //. rulesSingle;
symbCWithReplacementsMulti = parifSCHeld //. rulesMulti;
cStrings = 
  "DLLEXPORT" <> " " <> ToCCodeString@First@# & /@ 
   Join[symbCWithReplacementsSingle, symbCWithReplacementsMulti];
cFunctionsString = StringRiffle[cStrings, "\n\n"];

boilerPlate = "
  #include \"WolframLibrary.h\"

  /* Return the version of Library Link */
  DLLEXPORT mint WolframLibrary_getVersion( ) {
  \treturn WolframLibraryVersion;
  }

  /* Initialize Library */
  DLLEXPORT int WolframLibrary_initialize( WolframLibraryData \
libData) {
  \treturn LIBRARY_NO_ERROR;
  }

  /* Uninitialize Library */
  DLLEXPORT void WolframLibrary_uninitialize( WolframLibraryData \
libData) {
  \treturn;
  }

  ";

totalCString = boilerPlate <> cFunctionsString;
```

The code below creates the library.

```
libName = "parif";
CreateLibrary[totalCString, libName]
```

This loads the functions (again duplicate code)

```
parifFunctionsSingle = 
  LibraryFunctionLoad[
     libName, #2, {{#, 1, "Shared"}, {#}}, {#, 2}] & @@@ 
   Transpose@{typeTable[[All, 1]], libraryFunctionNamesSingle};

Set @@ {ToExpression["parifSingle" <> #, InputForm, 
      Unevaluated], #2} & @@@ 
  Transpose@{typeTable[[All, 4]], parifFunctionsSingle};

parifFunctionsMulti = 
  LibraryFunctionLoad[
     libName, #2, {{#, 1, "Shared"}, {#, 1, "Shared"}}, {#, 2}] & @@@ 
   Transpose@{typeTable[[All, 1]], libraryFunctionNamesMulti};

Set @@ {ToExpression["parifMulti" <> #, InputForm, 
      Unevaluated], #2} & @@@ 
  Transpose@{typeTable[[All, 4]], parifFunctionsMulti};
```

**Timing comparisons**

```
betterish[a_List,const_]:=Transpose[{a,ConstantArray[const,Length@a]}];
arFlatWiz[a_,b_]:= ArrayFlatten[{{{a}\[Transpose],b}}];

nn=10^7;
randomIntegers=RandomInteger[100,nn];

(resB=betterish[randomIntegers,2])//RepeatedTiming//First
(resAFW=arFlatWiz[randomIntegers, 2])//RepeatedTiming//First
(resSI=parifSingleI[randomIntegers,2])//RepeatedTiming//First

resB === resAFW===resSI
```

gives

> ```
> 0.201
> 0.213
> 0.0769
> True
> ```

And

```
randomReals1=RandomReal[1,nn];
randomReals2=RandomReal[1,nn];

(resT=Transpose@{randomReals1, randomReals2})//RepeatedTiming//First
(resMRLL=parifMultiR[randomReals1,randomReals2])//RepeatedTiming//First

resMRLL===resT
```

gives

> ```
> 0.18
> 0.0838
> True
> ```

So indeed we are faster than `Transpose` here.

Comment: I don't like running the code I don't understand, unless I want to get it :)

Comment: @Kuba but don't you know how many little computer gnome calculator slaves are killed every time you run `Riffle` :P? You run that without knowing how it is implemented, don't you ;)?

Comment: This kind of logic will lead us to Assembler, won't it? :)

Comment: @Kuba ain't nobody got time for that, I have to hunt for my own food!

Comment: Exactly! :P (*4togo*)

Answer (score 4):

Kind of stolen from Kuba's earlier comment:

Another way to rewrite the original expression <strike>**if speed is not a huge concern**</strike>  is via <strike>`Thread`</strike> `Transpose` as in:

```
Transpose[{{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}}]
```

which is especially pleasing to the eye if your initial lists are named variables (`Transpose@{a, b}`). <strike>On my machine this variant seems to be 10 times slower than the original `Riffle` and `Partition`.</strike>

The advantage and reason for posting (besides being easier to read) is that this construct can be used to merge more than two lists which is especially handy for e.g. `ListContourPlot`

```
ListContourPlot@Transpose[{xValues, yValues, fValues}]
```

Answer (score 4):

Since you only give two examples of your use of `Riffle` and `Partition`, and since I don't make common use of this combination myself, I can only address those specific examples.

The first can be done nearly an order of magnitude faster on packed arrays with a naive application of `Transpose` (as already mentioned by Kuba):

```
a = Range[3*^6];
b = Mod[a, 10];
Partition[Riffle[a, b], 2]  // timeAvg
{a, b}\[Transpose]          // timeAvg
```

> ```
> 0.03928
>
> 0.005616
> ```

(Search the site for `timeAvg` code; I have posted it *many* times.)

The second can be done several times faster with `ArrayFlatten`:

```
a = Range[3*^6]; b = 6;

Partition[Riffle[a, b, {2, -1, 2}], 2] // timeAvg
ArrayFlatten[{{{a}\[Transpose], b}}]   // timeAvg
```

> ```
> 0.04992
>
> 0.01684
> ```

For other methods and timings see this closely related Q&A:  [Prepend 0 to sublists](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/7996/121)