# Generating a list of numbers that are not multiples of 4

Tags: list-manipulation

I want to write simple code that will list all numbers from $1$ to $n$ that are not multiples of $4$.

And in this case I consider that

```
n=100

For[i = 1, i <= n, i++, If[Mod[i, 4] != 0, Print[i]]]
```

And got the answer

> 1
>   2
>   3
>   5
>   6 
>   7
>   9
>   10
>   11
>   13
>   14
>   15
>   17
>   18
>   19
>   21
>   22
>   23
>   25
>   26
>   27
>   29
>   30
>   31
>   33
>   34
>   35
>   37
>   38
>   39
>   41
>   42
>   43
>   45
>   46
>   47
>   49
>   50
>   51
>   53
>   54
>   55
>   57
>   58
>   59
>   61
>   62
>   63
>   65
>   66
>   67
>   69
>   70
>   71
>   73
>   74
>   75
>   77
>   78
>   79
>   81
>   82
>   83
>   85
>   86
>   87
>   89
>   90
>   91
>   93
>   94
>   95
>   97
>   98
>   99

Now I would like to return an expression without using `Print`. Are there any other functions I can use?

Also I would like to know whether I can write the same code and get the same answer using `Table`.

Comment: You could do this: `range1[n_] := Floor[Range[1, n + 3/4, 4/3]]`

Comment: My answer below was written with a more general application in mind.  For this specific task, this does a nice job: `Flatten@Outer[Plus, 4 Range[0, 24], Range[3]]`.  (It produces a [packed array](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3496/what-is-a-mathematica-packed-array).)

Comment: Mariam, Don't forget you can accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!  (I noticed you haven't accepted any answers to any of your questions. Perhaps you did not know about this aspect of Stackexchange sites.)

Comment: Hey Michael , Hope you are doing great :) thanks for note , as to be honest I haven't know about it before . Thanks

Comment: NestList[a = 1; i = 0; a |->a + RotateRight[{2,1,1},++i][[1]], a, 74]    or,   equivalently,      NestList[a = 1; i = 0; a |-> a + {1, 1, 2}[[ Mod[++i, 3, 1] ]], a, 74]

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Why not:

```
Drop[Range @ 100, {4, -1, 4}]
```

Or:

```
Range[Range@3, 100, 4] ~Flatten~ {2, 1}
```

Comment: you may always find a couple of faster and concise solutions :)) +1.

Comment: I think this one also deserves attantion: `Union @@ Range[Range@3, 100, 4]`

Comment: @garej Thanks, and I like your `Union` variant.

Comment: @garej If going for speed I think `Flatten[Range[Range@3, 100, 4]\[Transpose], 1]` is faster than `Union` and also gives a packed array, but `Drop` is probably faster than anything non-C-compiled.

Comment: That is for sure. `Drop` is fastest - `0.011` for `10^6` range, `Flatten` is `0.014`, and Union is two times slower - `0.026`.

Comment: Hmm the kind of code I made maybe only works nicely in C. It was silly anyway

Answer (score 15):

A couple general approaches:

```
Table[If[Mod[i, 4] != 0, i, Unevaluated@Sequence[]], {i, 100}]

Reap[Do[If[Mod[i, 4] != 0, Sow[i]], {i, 100}]][[2, 1]]
```

Note that the [`Unevaluated@Sequence[]` thing](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3700/121) is not a beginner's trick...`Table` always creates an entry for each iteration, so skipping some of them turns out to be tricky.  [`Reap`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Reap.html) and [`Sow`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Sow.html) are one standard way to create table entries conditionally.

---

**Update 1:**
@garej's answer reminded me that in V10 [`Nothing`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Nothing.html) is an alternative to `Unevaluated@Sequence[]`:

```
Table[If[Mod[i, 4] != 0, i, Nothing], {i, 100}]
```

---

**Update 2:**
In the comments that it is pointed out that `Divisible[i, 4]` is faster than `Mod[i, 4] != 4`. So if speed is an issue, one might consider using it for this specific type of problem.  However, `Divisible[]`, `Nothing`, `Reap[]`, `Sow[]`, and `Sequence[]` are [not compilable](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1096/list-of-compilable-functions), so the whole approach is a poor one if speed on long lists, for which `Table[]` will try to compile its body, is an issue.  One could either develop a compilable code for `Table` or use another approach even better adapted to the special case of skipping multiples of an given integer.

```
n = 10^6;
d = 4;
Table[If[Divisible[i, d], Nothing, i], {i, n}]; //             (* not compilable *)
  RepeatedTiming // First
DeleteCases[Table[If[Mod[i, d] != 0, -1, i], {i, n}], -1]; //  (* compilable Table[] *)
  RepeatedTiming // First
Flatten@Outer[Plus, d * Range[0, n/d - 1], Range[d - 1]]; //   (* faster still *)
  RepeatedTiming // First
(*
  0.93
  0.26
  0.017
*)
```

If `n` is not divisible by `d`, then for the last method, one could generate a list that is slightly longer and trim it to the desired length with `Part`, `Take` or `Drop`; the extra processing would take a negligible amount of time.

Since the focus of the question seemed to be about how to translate C-like code that conditionally skips entries in a table, I thought a general answer would be most helpful. There may be faster approaches than `Outer[Plus,..]`, the search for which I will leave to others.  The timings were given merely to illustrate my claims about compilability.

If you are interested in speed, I would point out [Mr.Wizard's `Drop` method](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/108559/4999) which is faster than `Outer`, or the [`Floor` method](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/108591/4999) in my other answer, which is a little faster still.

Comment: Can you please also give me advice from where I can contiue to study Matematica?

Comment: @Mariam Here are some Q&A with recommendations for learning *Mathematica*: [(18)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/18), [(733)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/733), [(5059)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/5059).

Comment: `Divisible[]` can of course be used instead of `Mod[]`.

Comment: @garej For speed I'd use `Flatten@Outer[Plus, 4 Range[0, 10^6/4 - 1], Range[4 - 1]]`, which is 50 times faster than `Table`...maybe trim the table to length if the end point weren't a even multiple of the divisor.

Comment: @MichaelE2, that is nearly as fast as drop version, indeed.

Comment: @garej I hadn't read all the new answers yet...and, obviously, I hadn't tested for speed.  Well, it wastes a little memory and saves a lot of time. :)

Comment: @MichaelE2 You can replace `Unevaluated@Sequence[]` with `Nothing` starting with version 10.2.  Makes it a little less daunting for beginners.

Comment: @Edmund I so noted in my "Update 1" :)

Comment: @MichaelE2 Yes.  I see. Fingers are faster than the eyes. :-)

Comment: @MichaelE2, I would upvote twice if I could for your update 2. Could you clearify on thing. Is there a difference (connection) between ability of function to keep arrays packed and its compilability?

Comment: @garej Yes, WVM (the Wolfram Virtual Machine, the runtime environment for compiled functions) deals only with packed arrays (as well as single values, of course).  Some functions have limited implementations in the WVM that allow them to be compiled (e.g. [`Position`](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/900/how-to-find-rows-that-have-maximum-value/901#comment101453_901), the compiled version of which cannot accept a pattern as an argument).

Answer (score 13):

If you see `Select`, you may try `Cases`.

```
DeleteCases[Range[100], x_ /; Mod[x, 4] == 0]
```

If you see `Table`, you may try `Array`:

```
Array[If[Mod[#, 4] == 0, Nothing, #] &, 100]
```

One more method with `Table`:

```
Complement[Range[100], Table[i, {i, 0, 100, 4}]]
```

To make `PackedArray`, one may also use:

```
Partition[Range[100], 4][[;; , ;; 3]]//Flatten
```

or

```
Delete[List /@ Range[100][[4 ;; 100 ;; 4]]][Range[100]]
```

Comment: Much like your complement answer would be: `Complement[Range[100], Range[0, 99, 4]]`

Comment: @bills, I was just trying to comply with original OP's question about `Table`, but then the discussion moved away from the original post...

Answer (score 10):

Many ways to skin a cat:

```
    n = 100;
    m = 4;

    Select[Range[n], Mod[#, m] != 0 &]

    Flatten@Table[i + Range[0, m - 2], {i, 1, n, m}]
```

Comment: Hi ,Thanks lot your answer helps me .

Comment: Also I would like to know can I write the same code and got the same answer using table ?

Comment: Not entirely sure why you want to use `Table`, kinda superfluous: `Table[i, {i, Select[Range[100], Mod[#, 4] != 0 &]}]`

Comment: Actually I am trying to learn Wolfram Language now , and from http://www.wolfram.com/language/elementary-introduction/05-operations-on-lists.html I learnd that I also can use table to do this kind of simple codes , but didn't got the mind how ,

Comment: really thank you

Comment: David G. Thanks for edit ,

Answer (score 10):

I think one can use `Partition` this way:

```
Flatten @ Partition[Range @ 100, 3, 4]
```

Answer (score 6):

A joke solution:

```
CoefficientList[Series[(1 - x^4)/((1 - x)^2 (1 - x^3)), {x, 0, 20}], x]
```

Answer (score 6):

Another trick for the specific case (edit notice: I changed `Range` from type `Integer` to type `Real`, for a 35% or so speed-up):

```
Floor[
 (4./3*(1 - $MachineEpsilon)) * Range[3. * 10^2 / 4]
 ]
```

It's pretty fast:

```
foo = Floor[
    (4./3*(1 - $MachineEpsilon)) * Range[3. * 10^6 / 4]
    ]; // RepeatedTiming
(*  {0.0033, Null}  *)
```

It competes in speed with [Mr.Wizard's](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/108559/4999) `Drop` method, although not in elegance**:

```
foo2 = Drop[Range[10^6], {4, -1, 4}]; // RepeatedTiming
(*  {0.0043, Null}  *)

foo2 == foo
(*  True  *)
```

By the time the dodge `1 - $MachineEpsilon` causes inaccuracies, you'll be out of memory (or at least I will).

```
foo = Floor[
    (4./3*(1 - $MachineEpsilon)) * Range[3. * 10^8 / 4]
    ]; // RepeatedTiming
foo2 = Drop[Range[10^8], {4, -1, 4}]; // RepeatedTiming
foo2 == foo
(*
  {0.77, Null}
  {1.1, Null}
  True
*)
```

**My method may appear to be memory-competitive as well since it does not generate extra entries and drop them, but that's an illusion.  The multiplication causes the array essentially to be copied, doubling the memory usage.  Since the array is 75% of the full range, we actually use 1.5 times the memory.  This is observable on my machine when I push the limit to `n = 10^9`, when the extra swapping in my method slows it down (17.7 sec. vs. 15 sec.); however the result is still accurate.

---

**Appendix**

Two more ways to handle the particular problem, first posted in my comments below, remarkable only for adding to the seemingly endless string of methods in this Q&A:

```
Nearest[Unitize@Mod[Range[10^2], 4] -> Automatic, 1]            (* 0.12s for n = 10^6 *)
Flatten@SparseArray[Mod[Range[10^2], 4]]["NonzeroPositions"]    (* 0.030s for n = 10^6 *)
```

Comment: Gestalt? :)) +1

Comment: @garej I wonder how long this can go on.  Not fast, but not slow: `Nearest[Unitize@Mod[Range[10^2], 4] -> Automatic, 1]`.

Comment: There's also `Flatten@SparseArray[Mod[Range[10^6], 4]]["NonzeroPositions"]`, which is not too bad, about 4 times faster than `Nearest`.

Comment: Version of Outer: `Flatten@(4 Range[0, (10^6/4) - 1] + ConstantArray[Range@3, (10^6)/4])`

Answer (score 5):

There is this way of doing it:

```
range[n_] := 
  Catenate[
    NestList[# + 4 &, {1, 2, 3}, Floor[(n - 1)/4]]][[;; Min[-1, Mod[n, 4, 1] - 4]]]
```

Answer (score 5):

Also

```
n = 100;
Pick[Range@n, Range@n/4, _Rational]
```

> {1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 9, 10, 11, 13, 14, 15, 17, 18, 19, 21, 22, 23, 25, 
>   26, 27, 29, 30, 31, 33, 34, 35, 37, 38, 39, 41, 42, 43, 45, 46, 47, 
>   49, 50, 51, 53, 54, 55, 57, 58, 59, 61, 62, 63, 65, 66, 67, 69, 70, 
>   71, 73, 74, 75, 77, 78, 79, 81, 82, 83, 85, 86, 87, 89, 90, 91, 93, 
>   94, 95, 97, 98, 99}

i.e.

*Take the first $n$ integers, divide each element in this first list by 4, and pick the elements in the first list such that the corresponding element in the second list is an `Rational`*

or, with `Mod`,

```
Pick[Range@n, Mod[Range@n, 4], 1|2|3]
```

or, avoiding "computing" the 1...n list two times

```
With[{l = Range@n}, Pick[l, Mod[l, 4], Except[0, _Integer]]]
```

or even

```
With[{l = Range@n}, Pick[l, UnitStep[Mod[l, 4] - 1], 1]]
```

Answer (score 5):

Another approach

```
not4k[n_] := (4 # + {1, 2, 3}) & /@ (Range[Quotient[n, 4]] - 1) // Flatten
```

Answer (score 4):

**Edit**

With some help from [Coolwater](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/9754/coolwater) (see comments)

```
Pick[#, Sign@Mod[#, 4], 1] & @ Range[100]
```

> {1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 9, 10, 11, 13, 14, 15, 17, 18, 19, 21, 22, 23, 25, 
>   26, 27, 29, 30, 31, 33, 34, 35, 37, 38, 39, 41, 42, 43, 45, 46, 47, 
>   49, 50, 51, 53, 54, 55, 57, 58, 59, 61, 62, 63, 65, 66, 67, 69, 70, 
>   71, 73, 74, 75, 77, 78, 79, 81, 82, 83, 85, 86, 87, 89, 90, 91, 93, 
>   94, 95, 97, 98, 99}

Original Post

```
Pick[#, Sign@Mod[#, 4] & @ #, 1] & @ Range[100]
```

Comment: Why `& @ #` in the end of the 2nd argument?!

Comment: @Coolwater. Nice once. Thanks. Have modified as  you suggested.

Answer (score 4):

**LibraryLink function**

My intuition was off for `Compile`, so I had to see if things worked like I expected in C using LibraryLink. Here is the C code.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include "WolframLibrary.h"
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <limits.h>

DLLEXPORT mint WolframLibrary_getVersion( ) {
    return WolframLibraryVersion;}
DLLEXPORT int WolframLibrary_initialize( WolframLibraryData libData){
    return LIBRARY_NO_ERROR;}
DLLEXPORT void WolframLibrary_uninitialize( WolframLibraryData
                                           libData) {
    return;}

DLLEXPORT int nonMultsCondManMod(WolframLibraryData libData,
                                 mint Argc, MArgument *Args, MArgument Res)
{
    int err = LIBRARY_NO_ERROR;
    mint nn = MArgument_getInteger(Args[0]);
    mint mm = MArgument_getInteger(Args[1]);
    mint quot = nn/mm;
    mint rem = nn - quot*mm;
    mint resLen = (mm-1)*quot + rem;
    MTensor result;
    err = libData->MTensor_new(MType_Integer, 1, &resLen, &result);
    mint* dataPtr = libData->MTensor_getIntegerData(result);

    int ii;
    int jj = 1;
    int kk = 1;
    for (ii = 1; ii <= resLen; ii++) {
        *(dataPtr++) = jj++;
        if(kk == mm-1){
            jj++;
            kk = 1;
        } else{kk++;}
    }
    MArgument_setMTensor(Res, result);
    return LIBRARY_NO_ERROR;
}
```

To let *Mathematica* use the C code, we will make a string of the code and store it in the variable `cCodeString`. To do this, copy the code above, paste it between quotes `""` and click "Yes" in the dialog (to escape the characters).

```
cCodeString = (*Insert C code here*);
```

Now we process the code/string and make a function out of it.

```
<< CCompilerDriver`;
CreateLibrary[cCodeString, "nonMults"];
Quiet@LibraryUnload["nonMults"];
nonMultsCondManMod = 
  LibraryFunctionLoad["nonMults", 
   "nonMultsCondManMod", {Integer, Integer}, {Integer, 1}];
```

**Timing comparison**

```
mm = 4;
nn = 10^7;

(rJ = nonMultsCondManMod[nn, mm]) // RepeatedTiming // First
(rW1 = Drop[Range@nn, {mm, -1, mm}]) // RepeatedTiming // First
rJ === rW1
```

> ```
> 0.018
> 0.056
> True
> ```

---

**Sillyness**

It seems my intuition was a bit off and the kind of strategy shown below only works (kind of) nicely in C, see for example the code above, or [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/46667/35892) or [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/38679/4330). The simple code by Mr.Wizard is faster. I'll refrain from deleting the code below despite this.

This solution uses `Compile`. It also uses meta-programming to avoid any conditionals (`If`) or restructuring (`Select`, `Pick`), while still being quite general. Evaluate all the code again if you want to try e.g. `mm=2` (make a list of odd numbers). Of course all this overkill in a sense.

```
mm = 4;

hCompileBodyTemplate =
  # /. OwnValues[mm] &@
   Hold[
    quot = Quotient[nn, mm];
    rem = nn - quot*mm;
    res = ConstantArray[0, quot*(mm - 1) + rem];
    ii = 1;
    jj = 1;
    Do[
     token;
     jj++;
     ,
     quot
     ];
    Do[
     res[[ii++]] = jj++
     ,
     rem
     ];
    res
    ];

hInstructions =
  CompoundExpression @@@
   Hold @@
    Join @@@
     List@
      Table[
       Hold[res[[ii++]] = jj++]
       ,
       mm - 1
       ];

hTokenRule =
  Delete[Hold @@ {HoldPattern[token] -> hInstructions}, {1, 2, 0}];

hCompileBody =
  ReplaceAll @@ {
    hCompileBodyTemplate,
    Unevaluated @@ hTokenRule
    };

hToken2Rule =
  Delete[Hold @@ {HoldPattern[token2] -> hCompileBody}, {1, 2, 0}];

hCompileTemplate =
  Hold@
   Compile[
    {{nn, _Integer}},
    Block[{quot, rem, ii, jj, res},
     token2
     ]
    ];
heldCompile =
  ReplaceAll @@ {
    hCompileTemplate,
    Unevaluated @@ hToken2Rule
    };

cfu = Identity @@ heldCompile;
```

Example

```
cfu[22]
```

> ```
> {1,2,3,5,6,7,9,10,11,13,14,15,17,18,19,21,22}
> ```

**Message to OP (Mariam)**

I really directed my answer to other experienced users of this site. Perhaps I should have been more clear. Thank you for your message, now that I know that you intend to study all the answers I will try to make my answer more readable and educational.

There are at least two things that can be learned from this answer

1. There is a function `Compile` that can make certain code faster
2. In the Wolfram Language (*Mathematica*) you can use code to generate and/or manipulate code

With regards to point 1., that is, the fact that `Compile` exists, I would like to say that it can be tricky to get started with `Compile`, because it requires some specific knowledge of what code can be compiled.

Concerning point 2, this manipulation and generation of code can be called meta-programming. This arguably an even more advanced (and useless) topic than `Compile`.

For example C++ also has some abilities to do meta-programming, mostly because of its flexible preprocessor, which is really a language all by itself. One (kind of) special thing about meta-programming in *Mathematica* is that you can use (many of) the same functions that would normally use to manipulate data to instead manipulate code.

In my answer I first generate some instructions and then insert them into my code. You can see that the `token` in the code above was replaced by three identical instructions `res[[ii++]] = jj++;`. The code that is generated looks as follows.

```
quot = Quotient[nn, 4];
rem = nn - quot 4;
res = ConstantArray[0, quot (4 - 1) + rem];
ii = 1;
jj = 1;
Do[
  (res[[ii++]] = jj++;
   res[[ii++]] = jj++;
   res[[ii++]] = jj++); jj++;,
  quot
  ];
Do[
 res[[ii++]] = jj++,
 rem]; 
res
```

Instead of bothering with how meta-programming or `Compile` works, perhaps you can first try to see why the generated code works for your question. A simpler version of the code above is this

```
nn = 22;
mm = 4;
quot = Quotient[nn, mm];
rem = nn - quot * mm;
resultLength = quot (mm - 1) + rem;
res = ConstantArray[0, resultLength];
jj = 1;
Do[
  res[[ii++]] = jj++;
  If[
   Divisible[jj , mm],
   jj++
   ]
  ,
  {ii, 1, resultLength}
  ];
res
```

And making it "more normal", we get this

```
nn = 22;
mm = 4;
quot = Quotient[nn, mm];
rem = nn - quot * mm;
resultLength = quot (mm - 1) + rem;
jj = 0;
res =
 Table[
  jj++;
  If[Divisible[jj , mm], jj++];
  jj
  ,
  {ii, 1, resultLength}
  ]
```

If we do not try to be so clever to predict the length of the result beforehand, we can end up with something that was already mentioned in other answers

```
nn = 22;
mm = 4;
res =
 Table[
  If[Divisible[jj , mm], Nothing, jj]
  ,
  {jj, 1, nn}
  ]
```

I recommend starting with this last piece of code and trying to see why the piece of code above it does the same thing.

Comment: @Mariam you are welcome. Please study the other answers first (and don't feel obliged to study my answer)!

Comment: to be honest  I am trying to study all answers. )

Comment: @Mariam ok, I have updated my answer to help you with your study. I have added the section Message to OP (Mariam), other than that nothing is new.

Comment: Perhaps I should say that Michael`s [second answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/108591/4330) and J.M's [joke answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/108569/4330) are also hard to understand (and not very serious), I recommend looking at the other answer first.

Comment: really thanks lot for your kind help , I am trying  to do all my best for studing Mathematica , and you answer and support helps me lot ,

Comment: @Mariam no problem, you can let me know if you have any questions (also about other answers). But I guess also at some point it would be nice to do a new exercise :).

Comment: yeah that's :) Thanks lot

Answer (score 4):

I grabbed the sequence from [jacob akkerboom](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/4330/jacob-akkerboom)'s post:

> FindSequenceFunction[{1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 9, 10, 11, 13, 14, 15, 17, 18,
>       19, 21, 22}, n] // FullSimplify

to get:

`Table[1/9 (-6 + 12 n - 3 Cos[(2 n Pi)/3] + Sqrt[3] Sin[(2 n Pi)/3]),{n,1,17}]`

**edited to show as table**

Comment: Yeah :) Thanks @Fred

Comment: Aha, so `Table[4 n + Mod[-n, 3] - 3, {n, 1, 22}]/3` also works!

Comment: And also: `Table[4 n + Sin[-2 (n + 1) Pi /3]*2/Sqrt[3] - 2, {n, 1, 22}]/3`. Haha you have opened a new door to new possibilities :P.

Comment: You could also use `SeriesCoefficient[]` on the function featured in my answer to obtain this result.

Comment: @J.M. and conversely, `GeneratingFunction[(4 n + Sin[-2 (n + 1) Pi/3]*2/Sqrt[3] - 2)/3, n, x] == jmExpr`. Also works with the `Mod` and mr Kline's expression.

Answer (score 3):

I've arrived late at this party. A complementary approach:

```
 Complement[Range[100], Range[4, 100, 4]]
```

... seems quite fast too.

Answer (score 1):

Do it with image processing!

```
PixelValuePositions[Image[{
  Flatten[ConstantArray[{0, 0, 0, 1}, {1, 100/4}]]
}], 0][[All, 1]]
```

A generalized function:

```
fun[len_, drop_] := PixelValuePositions[Image[{Flatten[ConstantArray[
      Append[ConstantArray[0, drop - 1], 1], {1, len/drop}]
    ]}], 0][[All, 1]]
```

It's not too slow either:

```
fun[10^7, 4]; // RepeatedTiming // First
1.31
```

Comment: Hey :) thanks @shrx

Answer (score 0):

```
Complement[Range@100, FindDivisions[{1, 100, 4}, 50]]
```

Will get what you want.

---

As the documentation this code could do this thing,but unfortunately there is a bug persisted long time in this function havenot been fixed.

```
Complement[Range@100, FindDivisions[{1, 100, 4}]]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Select[Range@100, Mod[#, 4] != 0 &]
```