# What is the most efficient way to replace items in a list at periodic intervals?

Tags: list-manipulation, performance-tuning

For example, if I want a list of $\phi(n)$ for $1 \leq n \leq 100$ but if $n$ is a multiple of 3 I want to show a 3 instead of $\phi(n)$. I tried

```
ReplacePart[EulerPhi[Range[100]], Table[{3n}, {n, 33}] -> 3]
```

but this just feels wrong.

Or a somewhat more involved example: show $4n$ except when $n \equiv 1 \pmod 4$, in which case show just $n$.

I am aware both of these can be accomplished with `If`. But there's a better way, isn't there?

Comment: `expr = Range[20]; expr[[3 ;; ;; 3]] = 3;expr`

Comment: @march was about to write that...

Comment: `expr = 4 Range[20]; expr[[Range[1, 20, 4]]] = Range[1, 20, 4]; expr` :)))

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you're okay with modifying the saved expression:

```
expr = Range[10]
expr[[3 ;; ;; 3]] = 3;
expr
(* {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10} *)
(* {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 3, 7, 8, 3, 10} *)
```

If you're not:

```
expr = Range[10];
MapAt[3 &, expr, {3 ;; ;; 3}]
(* {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 3, 7, 8, 3, 10} *)
```

A modified version of OP's

```
ReplacePart[expr, List /@Range[3, Length@expr, 3] -> 3]
```

---

For the second example, a modified version of OP:

```
expr = Range[10]^2
ReplacePart[expr, Thread[Range[1, 10, 4] -> Range[1, 10, 4]]]
(* {1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81, 100} *)
(* {1, 4, 9, 16, 5, 36, 49, 64, 9, 100} *)
```

and also

```
MapIndexed[If[Mod[First@#2, 4] == 1, First@#2, #1] &, expr]
Module[{i = -3}, MapAt[(i = i + 4) &, expr, {;; ;; 4}]]
```

Comment: Interesting Part specification for `MapAt`. Documented?

Comment: @unlikely. I don't know. I learned that here! But there is this hint in the documentation: "MapAt works on Association objects, using the same specification for keys as in Part."

Comment: @march, here is another option: `# /. Thread[Take[#, {3, -1, 3}] -> 3] &@Range[10]`

Answer (score 3):

```
  If[Mod[#, 3] == 0, 3, EulerPhi[#]] & /@ Range[10]
  If[Mod[#, 4] == 1, #, 4 #] & /@ Range[10]
```

Answer (score 3):

`Riffle` version (relatively fast, by the way):

```
Riffle[Drop[Range[10], {3, -1, 3}], 3, 3]
```

> `{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 3, 7, 8, 3, 10}`

---

For the second part, using @march:

```
expr = Range[10]^2;
expr[[Range[1, 10, 4]]] = Range[1, 10, 4]; expr
```

> `{1, 4, 9, 16, 5, 36, 49, 64, 9, 100}`

Comment: The `Riffle` version is very fast! +1. Here's a `Riffle` for the second part: `Riffle[Drop[Range[10]^2, {1, -1, 4}], Range[1, 10, 4], {1, -1, 4}]`.

Comment: @march, wow, I've missed such extension of `Riffle`, thanks for the tip...

Answer (score 3):

You can use pattern also:

```
 ReplacePart[{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}, n_ /; IntegerQ[n/3] :> 3]
```

I did not understand the second part of your question so I did not post answer for that.

Comment: You could've used `Divisible[n, 3]` for the test.

Answer (score 1):

This answer uses a function defined in my answer [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/108557/4330). If you find the definition too complicated, also see [Mr.Wizards answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/108559/4330).

This does not calculate `EulerPhi` more often than necessary.

```
Riffle[EulerPhi /@ nonMultsCondManMod[10, 3], 3, {3, -1, 3}]
```

For the more involved example

```
nn = 20;
mm = 4;
Riffle[mm (nonMultsCondManMod[nn, mm] + 1), 
 Range[1, nn, mm], {1, -mm, mm}]
```