# Most efficient way of making pair list from a list

Tags: list-manipulation, performance-tuning

I have a bunch of datasets which look like:

```
3 7 1 6 5
8 2 4 1 2
8 1 5 2 5
...
```

and I need to make a list of pairs such that the first element makes a pair with other elements in the same line.

```
3 7 
3 1
3 6
...
```

I usually use `Table` because it is fast enough for $10^3$ elements, but as my dataset gets bigger, it's no longer efficient. For example:

```
data = RandomInteger[{1, 10}, {10^7, 5}];
Flatten[Table[{data[[i, 1]], data[[i, j]]}, {i, 1, Length@data}, {j, 
 2, 5}], 1]//AbsoluteTiming//First
(* 39.828744 *)
```

What is the most efficient way to find this pair list?

### Timing

Finally I had a chance to do a timing on my real machine:

```
(* Kuba *)
0.726869
(* ciao *)
1.297926
(* nested table*)
2.146111
(* Shutao Tang *)
11.290944
(* Mr.Wizard♦ *)
57.232387
```

Although it seems results can be (completely) different if I do a timing on my old laptop!

Comment: Are the elements always a machine size `Integer`?  Or always a machine-precision `Real`?  Or mixture of different types of data?

Comment: @MichaelE2: They're always `Integer`.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

About 4x faster:

```
Partition[Flatten @ data[[All, {1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 4, 1, 5}]], 2]
```

Comment: Shouldn't you make this more general?

Comment: It depends. If it is slow, probably doesn't matter. If it is fast, ok. But atm I'm confused because I'm testing your and rasher's method with result that your is 20x slower than OP's. So as soon as I figure it out I will tell you :P

Comment: LOL -- looks like I wrote a function for the wrong shape of data.  Okay, +1, and back to the drawing board.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Ok :) I have to go but I will make it more general tomorrow, if it is worth it :). Feel free to delete my non relevant comments when you change something. Good night. :)

Comment: Ah, clean. I feel herp-a-derp for not thinking of that... +1

Answer (score 10):

I think you'll find this faster:

```
pairem[data_] := 
 Module[{c = ConstantArray[0, 8*(Length@data)], 
   p = Flatten@data[[All, 2 ;;]], p2 = data[[All, 1]]},
  c[[2 ;; ;; 2]] = p;
  c[[1 ;; ;; 2]] = Flatten@Transpose[ConstantArray[p2, 4]];
  Partition[c, 2]]
```

Comment: @Pickett I don't know, I still get only 2.5 speed up here, maybe it is hardware related.

Answer (score 5):

*Edit:* this method is optimized for long sublists which is exactly the opposite of your example.  Sorry.  I'll post if I find anything applicable.

---

This is fairly clean and on larger data at least as fast as rasher's code:

```
fn = ArrayFlatten[{{First@#, Rest@# ~Partition~ 1 }}] &;
```

Test:

```
fn /@ {{3, 7, 1, 6, 5}, {8, 2, 4, 1, 2}, {8, 1, 5, 2, 5}}
```

> ```
> {{{3, 7}, {3, 1}, {3, 6}, {3, 5}},
>  {{8, 2}, {8, 4}, {8, 1}, {8, 2}},
>  {{8, 1}, {8, 5}, {8, 2}, {8, 5}}}
> ```

```
x = RandomInteger[99, {5000, 5000}];

fn /@ x   // AbsoluteTiming // First
pairem[x] // AbsoluteTiming // First
```

> ```
> 0.334019
>
> 0.383022
> ```

A related question: [Prepend 0 to sublists](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/7996/121)

Comment: Try with `x = RandomInteger[99, {10^6, 5}]` which is really the case.

Comment: @Kuba, `x = RandomInteger[99, {10^6, 5}];pairem[x]; // AbsoluteTiming   fn /@ x; // AbsoluteTiming`  ===>  `{0.2158204, Null},{13.1357421, Null}`

Answer (score 4):

Here is a refinement of @Kuba's clever [`Part`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Part) syntax:

```
data = RandomInteger[{1,10},{10^7,5}];

r1 = Partition[
    Flatten @ data[[All,{1,2,1,3,1,4,1,5}]],
    2
]; //AbsoluteTiming

r2 = ArrayReshape[
    data[[All, {1,2,1,3,1,4,1,5}]],
    {4 Length[data], 2}
]; //AbsoluteTiming

r1===r2
```

> {1.55516, Null}
>
> {0.568824, Null}
>
> True

Answer (score 3):

**My trail:**

```
data = RandomInteger[{1, 10}, {8, 5}]
```

> ```
> {{1, 1, 9, 10, 6}, {7, 2, 8, 5, 4}, {2, 1, 10, 1, 7}, {9, 1, 4, 5, 2},
>    {6, 10, 6, 5, 10}, {2, 10, 1, 7, 4}, {3, 5, 3, 2, 2}, {1, 2, 9, 6, 2}}
> ```

```
Thread@{#1, {##2}} & @@@ data
```

> ```
> {
>    {{1, 1}, {1, 9}, {1, 10}, {1, 6}}, {{7, 2}, {7, 8}, {7, 5}, {7, 4}},
>    {{2, 1}, {2, 10}, {2, 1}, {2, 7}}, {{9, 1}, {9, 4}, {9, 5}, {9, 2}},
>    {{6, 10}, {6, 6}, {6, 5}, {6, 10}}, {{2, 10}, {2, 1}, {2, 7}, {2, 4}},  
>    {{3, 5}, {3, 3}, {3, 2}, {3, 2}}, {{1, 2}, {1,9}, {1, 6}, {1, 2}}
> }
> ```

**Performance test**

```
x = RandomInteger[99, {10^6, 5}];
Thread@{#1, {##2}} & @@@ x; // AbsoluteTiming
```

> ```
> {2.3535156, Null}
> ```

Comment: Pretty, so +1, but much slower even than OP code, who is looking for efficiency.

Comment: @rasher, The high-efficiency methods are `pairem` and @Kuba method currently

Answer (score 2):

Just for fun a solution with Riffle:

```
riffle[d_] := Module[{data = Transpose[d]},
  Partition[Flatten[Transpose[Rest[Riffle[data, {First[data]}]]]], 2]
  ]
```