# Inserting columns multiple times

Tags: list-manipulation

I think this question is very simple and will be closed, but I'm left with doubts.

```
transform = CoordinateTransformData["Polar" -> "Cartesian", "Mapping"];
{p1, p2, p3, p4, p5, p6} = 
 transform[{2 Sqrt[3], # Degree}] & /@ Most[Subdivide[360, 6] + 30] //
   N
```

> $\left(
> \begin{array}{cc}
>  3. & 1.73205 \\
>  0. & 3.4641 \\
>  -3. & 1.73205 \\
>  -3. & -1.73205 \\
>  0. & -3.4641 \\
>  3. & -1.73205 \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$

How could I apply the insert function to get this result?

```
Join[{{3., 1.7320508075688772, 0}, {0., 3.4641016151377544, 0}, {-3., 
   1.7320508075688772, 0}, {-3., -1.7320508075688772, 
   0}, {0., -3.4641016151377544, 0}, 
     {3., -1.7320508075688772, 0}}, {{3., 1.7320508075688772, 
   15}, {0., 3.4641016151377544, 15}, {-3., 1.7320508075688772, 
   15}, {-3., -1.7320508075688772, 15}, {0., -3.4641016151377544, 15}, 
     {3., -1.7320508075688772, 15}}]
```

> $\left(
> \begin{array}{ccc}
>  3. & 1.73205 & 0 \\
>  0. & 3.4641 & 0 \\
>  -3. & 1.73205 & 0 \\
>  -3. & -1.73205 & 0 \\
>  0. & -3.4641 & 0 \\
>  3. & -1.73205 & 0 \\
>  3. & 1.73205 & 15 \\
>  0. & 3.4641 & 15 \\
>  -3. & 1.73205 & 15 \\
>  -3. & -1.73205 & 15 \\
>  0. & -3.4641 & 15 \\
>  3. & -1.73205 & 15 \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$

Comment: Have you tried `PadRight`?

Comment: Not yet. I will read about it.

Comment: I think there no solution with `Insert` only. Otherwise there are plenty of solutions. I would do something like this : `Join[Insert[#, 0, -1] & /@ {p1, p2, p3, p4, p5, p6},  Insert[#, 15, -1] & /@ {p1, p2, p3, p4, p5, p6}]`

Comment: Related: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/7996/121

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using [lowriniak's](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/133903/inserting-columns-multiple-times#comment361184_133903) comment:

```
transform = CoordinateTransformData["Polar" -> "Cartesian", "Mapping"];
{p1, p2, p3, p4, p5, p6} = 
 transform[{2 Sqrt[3], # Degree}] & /@ Most[Subdivide[360, 6] + 30] //
   N
```

> $\left(
> \begin{array}{cc}
>  3. & 1.73205 \\
>  0. & 3.4641 \\
>  -3. & 1.73205 \\
>  -3. & -1.73205 \\
>  0. & -3.4641 \\
>  3. & -1.73205 \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$

Through [`PadRight`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PadRight.html) function:

```
Join[PadRight[{p1, p2, p3, p4, p5, p6}, {6, 3}], 
 PadRight[{p1, p2, p3, p4, p5, p6}, {6, 3}, {15}]]
```

> $\left(
> \begin{array}{ccc}
>  3. & 1.73205 & 0 \\
>  0. & 3.4641 & 0 \\
>  -3. & 1.73205 & 0 \\
>  -3. & -1.73205 & 0 \\
>  0. & -3.4641 & 0 \\
>  3. & -1.73205 & 0 \\
>  3. & 1.73205 & 15 \\
>  0. & 3.4641 & 15 \\
>  -3. & 1.73205 & 15 \\
>  -3. & -1.73205 & 15 \\
>  0. & -3.4641 & 15 \\
>  3. & -1.73205 & 15 \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$

Answer (score 3):

Behold [`ArrayFlatten`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ArrayFlatten.html)

```
pn = {p1, p2, p3, p4, p5, p6};

ArrayFlatten[{{pn, 0}, {pn, 15}}] // MatrixForm
```

> $\left(
> \begin{array}{ccc}
>  3. & 1.73205 & 0 \\
>  0. & 3.4641 & 0 \\
>  -3. & 1.73205 & 0 \\
>  -3. & -1.73205 & 0 \\
>  0. & -3.4641 & 0 \\
>  3. & -1.73205 & 0 \\
>  3. & 1.73205 & 15 \\
>  0. & 3.4641 & 15 \\
>  -3. & 1.73205 & 15 \\
>  -3. & -1.73205 & 15 \\
>  0. & -3.4641 & 15 \\
>  3. & -1.73205 & 15 \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$

Answer (score 3):

Also

```
Distribute[{{0, 15}, pn}, List, List, List, Append[#2, #] &] // MatrixForm
```

or

```
Join @@ Outer[Append[#2, #] &,  {0, 15}, pn, 1] // MatrixForm
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

**Note:** you can use `Insert[#2, #, -1] &` instead of `Append[#2, #]` in the above.