# Appending multiple elements to sublists

Tags: list-manipulation, function-construction

In short, I look for a **concise** definition of a function in Mathematica that calculates the following:

$f\left(\begin{pmatrix}a_{11}&\dots&a_{1m}\\\vdots&\ddots&\vdots\\a_{n1}&\dots&a_{nm}\\\end{pmatrix},\left(b_1,\dots,b_p\right)\right)=\begin{pmatrix}a_{11}&\dots&a_{1m}&b_1&\dots&b_p\\\vdots&\ddots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots\\a_{n1}&\dots&a_{nm}&b_1&\dots&b_p\\\end{pmatrix}$

An example would be:

$f\left(\begin{pmatrix}a&b\\c&d\\\end{pmatrix},\left(e,f\right)\right)=\begin{pmatrix}a&b&e&f\\c&d&e&f\\\end{pmatrix}$

I already developed a few solutions, but none is really short *and* in direct use of built-in functions:

```
f1[matrix_, list_] := Join[#, list] & /@ matrix
```

This is the shortest I came up with, but I'm not sure a `Map` is the most sensible approach here.

```
f2[matrix_, {list__}] := Replace[matrix, {a__} -> {a, list}, {1}]
```

Less short, but directly using Mathematica functions.

```
f3[matrix_, list_] := Join[matrix, ConstantArray[list, Length[matrix]], 2]
```

Unnecessary `ConstantArray`.

None of these really seem to fulfil the requirement set.

Comment: Related: [(189)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/189/121), [(7996)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/7996/121), [(133903)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/133903/121)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look at [`ArrayFlatten`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ArrayFlatten.html):

```
fn[matrix_, {x__}] := ArrayFlatten[{{matrix, x}}]

fn[{{a, b}, {c, d}}, {e, f}] // MatrixForm
```

> $\left(
> \begin{array}{cccc}
>  a & b & e & f \\
>  c & d & e & f \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$

Answer (score 2):

```
aa = Array[a, {4, 4}];
bb = Array[b, {2}];

ArrayPad[#, {{0}, {0, Length@#2}}, #2] &[aa, bb]
(* or *) Distribute[{#, {#2}}, List, List, List, Join] &[aa, bb]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]