# Prepending a constant value to sublists of a list

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a `list`:

```
list =
{
{{1,1,{1,1}},{1,2,{2,2}},{1,3,{3,3}},{1,4,{4,4}},{1,5,{5,5}}},
{{2,1,{1.01,1.01}},{2,2,{2.01,2.01}},{2,3,{3.01,3.01}},{2,4,{4.01,4.01}},{2,5,{5.01,5.01}}},
{{3,1,{1.02,1.02}},{3,2,{2.02,2.02}},{3,3,{4.02,4.02}},{3,4,{5.02,5.02}}},
{{4,1,{1.52,1.52}},{4,2,{2.03,2.03}},{4,3,{3.52,3.52}},{4,4,{4.03,4.03}},{4,5,{5.03,5.03}}},
{{5,1,{1.53,1.52}},{5,2,{2.53,2.53}},{5,3,{3.53,3.53}},{5,4,{4.53,4.53}},{5,5,{5.054,5.54}}},
{{6,1,{1.54,1.54}},{6,2,{3.53,3.53}},{6,3,{3.54,3.54}},{6,4,{4.54,4.54}},{6,5,{6.054,6.54}}}
};
```

Now I want to prepend to each sublist item a `-1`, so that I get:

```
{
{{-1,1,1,{1,1}},{-1,1,2,{2,2}},{-1,1,3,{3,3}},{-1,1,4,{4,4}},{-1,1,5,{5,5}}},  
{{-1,2,1,{1.01,1.01}},{-1,2,2,{2.01,2.01}},{-1,2,3,{3.01,3.01}},{-1,2,4,{4.01,4.01}},{-1,2,5,{5.01,5.01}}},
{{-1,3,1,{1.02,1.02}},{-1,3,2,{2.02,2.02}},{-1,3,3,{4.02,4.02}},{-1,3,4,{5.02,5.02}}},
{{-1,4,1,{1.52,1.52}},{-1,4,2,{2.03,2.03}},{-1,4,3,{3.52,3.52}},{-1,4,4,{4.03,4.03}},{-1,4,5,{5.03,5.03}}},
{{-1,5,1,{1.53,1.52}},{-1,5,2,{2.53,2.53}},{-1,5,3,{3.53,3.53}},{-1,5,4,{4.53,4.53}},{-1,5,5,{5.054,5.54}}},
{{-1,6,1,{1.54,1.54}},{-1,6,2,{3.53,3.53}},{-1,6,3,{3.54,3.54}},{-1,6,4,{4.54,4.54}},{-1,6,5,{6.054,6.54}}}
}
```

To do that I could use:

```
Prepend[#, -1] & /@ list[[#]] & /@ Range[Length[list]]
```

Do you know another solution for that?

Comment: Related: [(7996)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/7996/121)

Comment: FWIW if your third sub-array were not shorter than the others you could use `ArrayPad[list, {0, 0, {1, 0}}, -1]` -- this may still prove useful in other applications.  In *this* case we would need `ArrayPad[#, {0, {1, 0}}, -1] & /@ list` which seems clumsy compared to other methods.

Comment: @ Mr.Wizard: unfortunately in my original data the sub-arrays can all have slightly different lengths.

Comment: `ArrayFlatten[{{-1, #}}] & /@ list` (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/2274679/499167)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

### Rewriting other's using operator forms

I like @eldo's  solution, but it can be shorter!

```
Map[Prepend[-1], list, {2}]
```

Same for @aardvark2012's

```
Map[Insert[-1, 1], list, {2}]
```

### Solutions of my own

```
list[[All, All, 0]] = Prepend[-1]@*List;
```

Or better

```
list[[All, All, 0]] = {-1, ##} &;
```

Also as an operator

```
ReplacePart[{_, _, 0} -> ({-1, ##} &)]
```

### Best other

Given that the OP accepted mine (hastily to my taste and despite the good quality of the others), I want to highlight this answer given by Mr.Wizard in a comment to another answer. Easy to understand, and short:

```
Map@Prepend[-1] /@ list
```

Comment: I quite like `list[[All, All, 0]] = {-1, ##} &;`.  Already upvoted.

Comment: Thank you for the different solutions ...

Answer (score 8):

```
☺ = {-1, ##} & @@@ # & /@ # &; 

☺ @ list
```

(* thanks: Mr.Wizard *)

Comment: Shorter: `{-1, ##} & @@@ # & /@ # &`

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, yes!

Comment: @Mr.Wizard `{-1, ##}&@@@#&/@list` is really very very nice! (And @kglr, of course I like the smilies and the typographic minimalism in v2 :-) )

Comment: @John I have [long](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/7996/prepend-0-to-sublists#comment22841_7997) enjoyed `##` and `@@@` and I like the newer operator forms of v10, so I find `☺ = Map[{-1, ##} & @@@ # &]` a pleasing combination.

Answer (score 7):

If we're golfing ;-)

```
Prepend[-1]/@#&/@list
```

Comment: Oh, nicely played!

Comment: Also `Map@Prepend[-1] /@ list`

Comment: @Mr.Wizard: I like this solution in the comment very much ...

Comment: @mrz Thank you.

Answer (score 7):

Using [`Outer`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Outer.html)

```
Outer[Prepend[-1], list, 2]
```

Comment: I don't know if I've ever seen `Outer` used this way. Even if it's just my memory failing me again thanks for showing me something unexpected.

Answer (score 6):

```
Map[Prepend[#, -1] &, list, {2}]
```

Answer (score 6):

One possibility:

```
Map[Join[{-1}, #] &, list, {2}]
```

Edit 1: or

```
Map[Insert[#, -1, 1] &, list, {2}]
```

(possibly faster on large lists).

Edit 2: or

```
ArrayPad[#, {{0, 0}, {1, 0}}, -1] & /@ list
```

Answer (score 6):

```
Replace[list, a___ :> Catenate@{{-1}, a}, {2}]
```

Answer (score 6):

Adding `Query` to the mix:

```
list // Query[All, All, Prepend[-1]]
```

Answer (score 2):

A `Flatten[]` variation:

```
Flatten[{ConstantArray[{-1}, Length[#]] & /@ list, list}, {{2}, {3}, {1, 4}}]
```