# Combining list elements

Tags: list-manipulation, performance-tuning

I am doing the following:

```
SeedRandom[1];
n = 3;
data = {RandomInteger[10], RandomInteger[10, {4, 5}]} & /@ Range[n]

{{1, {{4, 0, 7, 0, 0}, {8, 6, 0, 4, 1}, {8, 5, 1, 1, 1}, {3, 2, 10, 1, 6}}},
 {0, {{2, 6, 4, 5, 4}, {3, 0, 1, 3, 5}, {3, 0, 3, 2, 3}, {9, 5, 1, 5, 2}}},
 {3, {{9, 1, 0, 4, 4}, {1, 5, 2, 7, 9}, {9, 8, 10, 0, 10}, {10, 7, 4, 9, 2}}}}
```

The result should be:

```
Flatten[Table[Append[#, data[[i, 1]]] & /@ data[[i, 2]], {i, n}], 1]

{{4, 0, 7, 0, 0, 1}, {8, 6, 0, 4, 1, 1}, {8, 5, 1, 1, 1, 1}, {3, 2, 10, 1, 6, 1}, 
 {2, 6, 4, 5, 4, 0}, {3, 0, 1, 3, 5, 0}, {3, 0, 3, 2, 3, 0}, {9, 5, 1, 5, 2, 0}, 
 {9, 1, 0, 4, 4, 3}, {1, 5, 2, 7, 9, 3}, {9, 8, 10, 0, 10, 3}, {10, 7, 4, 9, 2, 3}}
```

Can you propose another FAST solution instead of using `Table`?

Comment: `Append @@@ Join @@ (Thread /@ Reverse /@ data)`?

Comment: @kglr: wau, please put this into an answer ... this is incredably fast

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Append @@@ Join @@ (Thread /@ Reverse /@ #) & @ data
```

> {{4, 0, 7, 0, 0, 1}, {8, 6, 0, 4, 1, 1}, {8, 5, 1, 1, 1, 1}, {3, 2, 0, 1, 6, 1}, 
>     {2, 6, 4, 5, 4, 0},
>     {3, 0, 1, 3, 5, 0}, {3, 0, 3, 2, 3, 0}, {9, 5, 1, 5, 2, 0},  {9, 1, 0, 4, 4, 3},
>     {1, 5, 2, 7, 9, 3}, {9, 8, 10, 0, 10, 3}, {10, 7, 4, 9, 2, 3}}

Comment: thanks a lot for the really FAST solution.

Answer (score 7):

[tomd](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/106/tomd) was close (+1) but there is better:

```
ArrayFlatten[data ~Reverse~ 2]
```

Related: [Prepend 0 to sublists](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/7996/121)

Comment: That is very nice!

Comment: I like that ... thanks a lot also for the link to your answer.

Comment: Off-topic question:Are you also the "Mr. Wizard" on the Outdoors SE forum [here](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/264/is-drinking-urine-safe)?

Comment: @Daniel, [yes, it's him](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/users/133/mr-wizard).

Comment: @J.M. Okay, good to know. I had an unfortunate need for the sort of info at that link yesterday.

Comment: @Daniel Yup, it's me.  I'm no *outdoorsman* but I enjoy nature.

Comment: Glad to hear. I am experimenting with a sun still in my back yard right now. Suffice it to say that it is the sort of thing I wish I had known about a couple of days ago.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau Yikes!  I was hoping your need was merely to dissuade an acquaintance from drinking the yellow stuff "for health."  (No I'm not making that up, some people actually do this...)  I guess you're OK now?

Comment: Nothing like that alas (I've also read people do that... bad idea). I am fine now, thanks. I got caught in a bad back-country low-water situation Friday evening/Saturday morning. Mostly my own stupidity (compounded by a drought in a less-than-familiar region). Kept the overnight "discharge" for emergency usage if needed. Would describe it as roughly equal parts coffee, tea, and ghastly. Not yet sure how I feel about outing myself as an idiot in public, so I might delete this in a while. Or not.

Answer (score 5):

```
ArrayFlatten[{#}] & /@ Reverse /@ data  // Catenate
```

> {{4, 0, 7, 0, 0, 1}, {8, 6, 0, 4, 1, 1}, {8, 5, 1, 1, 1, 1}, {3, 2, 
>     10, 1, 6, 1}, {2, 6, 4, 5, 4, 0}, {3, 0, 1, 3, 5, 0}, {3, 0, 3, 2, 
>     3, 0}, {9, 5, 1, 5, 2, 0}, {9, 1, 0, 4, 4, 3}, {1, 5, 2, 7, 9, 
>     3}, {9, 8, 10, 0, 10, 3}, {10, 7, 4, 9, 2, 3}}

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2274679/499167), due to [Janus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/212538/janus), at SO.

Slight modification of above:

```
ArrayFlatten[{#}] & /@ Reverse[data, 2] // Catenate
```

---

**Edit**

[Mr Wizard](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/121/mr-wizard), in [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/157754/106), gives an elegant modification:

```
Reverse[data, 2] // ArrayFlatten
```

---

Just for fun:

```
Flatten /@ Tuples[{ #[[2]], {#[[1]]}}] & /@ data // Catenate
```

Comment: Thank you ... this is also very fast and elegant too

Comment: `ArrayFlatten` is a really useful function. It's very good to try and get it into your repertoire.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
BlockRandom[SeedRandom[1]; 
            Table[With[{pad = RandomInteger[10]}, 
                       PadRight[RandomInteger[10, {4, 5}], {4, 6}, pad]], {3}]]
   {{{4, 0, 7, 0, 0, 1}, {8, 6, 0, 4, 1, 1}, {8, 5, 1, 1, 1, 1},
     {3, 2, 10, 1, 6, 1}},
    {{2, 6, 4, 5, 4, 0}, {3, 0, 1, 3, 5, 0}, {3, 0, 3, 2, 3, 0}, {9, 5, 1, 5, 2, 0}},
    {{9, 1, 0, 4, 4, 3}, {1, 5, 2, 7, 9, 3}, {9, 8, 10, 0, 10, 3}, {10, 7, 4, 9, 2, 3}}}
```

Comment: thank you ... in my real data the number of elements can be anything and is not fixed (my example does not show it)

Comment: Should've made a more representative example, then.

Answer (score 1):

```
list =
  {{1, {{4, 0, 7, 0, 0}, {8, 6, 0, 4, 1}, {8, 5, 1, 1, 1}, {3, 2, 10, 1, 6}}}, 
   {0, {{2, 6, 4, 5, 4}, {3, 0, 1, 3, 5}, {3, 0, 3, 2, 3}, {9, 5, 1, 5, 2}}}, 
   {3, {{9, 1, 0, 4, 4}, {1, 5, 2, 7, 9}, {9, 8, 10, 0, 10}, {10, 7, 4, 9, 2}}}};
```

`MapApply` came with V 13.1

```
Join @@ MapApply[Append @ #1 /@ #2 &] @ list
```

gives

```
{{4, 0, 7, 0, 0, 1}, {8, 6, 0, 4, 1, 1}, {8, 5, 1, 1, 1, 1}, {3, 2, 10, 1, 6, 1},
 {2, 6, 4, 5, 4, 0}, {3, 0, 1, 3, 5, 0}, {3, 0, 3, 2, 3, 0}, {9, 5, 1,5, 2, 0},
 {9, 1, 0, 4, 4, 3}, {1, 5, 2, 7, 9, 3}, {9, 8, 10, 0, 10, 3}, {10, 7,4, 9, 2, 3}}
```