# How can I transform tabular data so it can be plotted?

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation

[image: Output of a Table]

I have the following variable (see Picture). Note that it has 3 dimensions. In the example for the first row is

$\qquad (0, 0, 0.167588),\,(0 , 0.25, 0.171669),\,(0, 0.5, 0.172119), \,\ldots$

I need to plot this in a 3d Diagram. Therefore, I guess the variable has to be transformed in some way.

Comment: try this `frankwf1 // Map[Thread] // Flatten[#, 1] & // 
 ReplaceAll[{x_?NumericQ, {y_?NumericQ, z_?NumericQ}} :> {x, y, z}]`

Comment: or `frankwf1 // ReplaceAll[
  {x_?NumericQ, y : {{_?NumericQ, _?NumericQ} ..}} :> 
   Sequence @@ Map[Prepend[x], y]]`

Comment: Due to the way you have your list setup, the first row isn't actually (0, 0, 0.167588) as you think. Look at the curly brackets. The first row's first element is zero, and the second element is a list of ordered pairs. Try to make sets of ordered triplets for your 3-dimensions, and that should plot easily in 3d.

Comment: Copy and Paste code (InputForm) into your question rather than pictures of code. This will facilitate getting help.

Comment: `ArrayFlatten[list]` (after [Mr Wizard's answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/157754/106)) and [possible duplicate](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/157676/106)

Answer (score 3):

```
ListPlot3D[ArrayFlatten[frankwf1]]
```

[image]