# Making tuples with values produced by `Range[n]` and a constant $m$

Tags: list-manipulation

I'd like to produce a list of  $n-$tuples made from the elements of `Range[n]` coupled with a constant value $m$.

Here's an example, given $n=3$:

```
Range[3] = {1,2,3}
```

What I want to obtain is:

```
{{1,m},{2,m},{3,m}}
```

I've tried using `Tuple`, but I couldn't get it to make what I want.

Comment: Related: [(7996)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/7996/121)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can in fact use `Tuples[]`:

```
Tuples[{{1, 2, 3}, {"m"}}]
   {{1, "m"}, {2, "m"}, {3, "m"}}
```

Comment: Is the `"m"` the same as `m`?

Comment: You can replace `"m"` with anything else; try it out yourself.

Comment: I've tried. Thanks a lot! (Sorry if the question was a bit basic.)

Comment: @Rodrigo You can make explicit use of [`Symbol`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Symbol.html?q=Symbol) which I sometimes like to make the character of `m` more explicit, e.g. `Symbol["m"]`.

Answer (score 3):

Benchmark in *Mathematica* 10.1 of the posted methods, plus one using [`ArrayFlatten`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ArrayFlatten.html):

```
tuples[n_] := Tuples[{Range@n, {m}}];
thread[n_] := Thread[{Range@n, m}];
array[n_] := Array[{#, m} &, n];
transpose[n_] := Transpose@{Range@n, ConstantArray[m, n]};
arrayflatten[n_] := ArrayFlatten[{{Range@n ~Partition~ 1, m}}];

m = 17;

Needs["GeneralUtilities`"]
BenchmarkPlot[{tuples, thread, array, transpose, arrayflatten}, Identity]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
Block[{n = 3}, Array[{#, m} &, n]]
Transpose@{Range[3], ConstantArray[m, 3]} == %
Thread@{Range[3], m} == %%
```

> {{1, m}, {2, m}, {3, m}}
>
> True
>
> True