# Prepending different numbers to sublists

Tags: list-manipulation

This problem relates to [Prepend 0 to sublists](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/7996/prepend-0-to-sublists)
I have the list

```
t1 = Table[m = n + IntegerReverse[n]; n = m, {n, 3}, {i, 1, 4}]
```

giving

```
{{2, 4, 8, 16}, {4, 8, 16, 77}, {6, 12, 33, 66}}
```

But I want to start with the first value n so I should get

```
{{1, 2, 4, 8, 16}, {2, 4, 8, 16, 77}, {3, 6, 12, 33, 66}}
```

It can be done by

```
Prepend[#, #[[1]]/2] & /@ t1
```

But this is cheatingly awkward. How can I do it properly or within the Table command? I tried Hold and Prepend inside Table but did not get anywhere.

Comment: `Flatten /@ Thread[{Range[3], t1}]`  seems natural enough.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
MapIndexed[Join[#2, #] &, Table[n = n + IntegerReverse[n], {n, 3}, {i, 4}]]
```

> {{1, 2, 4, 8, 16}, {2, 4, 8, 16, 77}, {3, 6, 12, 33, 66}}

To get the same result using only `Table`:

```
Table[n = If[i == 0, n, n + IntegerReverse[n]], {n, 3}, {i, 0, 4}]
```

> {{1, 2, 4, 8, 16}, {2, 4, 8, 16, 77}, {3, 6, 12, 33, 66}}